# How to open "Type Declaration" in current window?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-studio-3.0

When I'm clicking on 
At `Keymap` there is the action `Type Declaration` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Button1 Click</kbd>
When I'm clicking on any variable with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Button1 Click</kbd> the class file opens in new window.

How to prevent opening it in new window, but open it in current window?

[image]

Comment: The mouse behavior in this case is a bug. As a workaround, you can invoke "Goto Type Declaration" from the keyboard (Ctrl-Shift-B in the default keymap), or reassign the shortcut to a combination that doesn't use the Shift key (Ctrl-Alt).

Comment: @yole thank you for idea, I solved it by adding another mouse shortcut `Alt+ Button1 Click`